# Why does SE have SO as stand-alone domain, and others as sub-domains?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

As the title states, why does Stack Exchange (SE) have Stack Overflow (SO) its' own domain, and yet everything else is just sub-domains under SE?

Is it because SO came first, and then SE was a product of that?

Just curious...

Comment: Not only Stack Overflow, [SOFU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44128/312043)

Comment: "Everything else" is not the case. The three "trilogy" sites are all custom URLs... so SO, SF, SU. There are also several other sites that have custom URLs but automatically convert to the XXX.SE format (seasonedadvice.com or arqade.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't the only site with its own domain.
All the members of the trilogy have their own domains:

- [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)
- [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)
- [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

The trilogy were the first three Stack Exchange sites. You can find more information on the blog:

- [The Stack Overflow Trilogy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/)

Custom domains was something tried for the later sites. It was given up and any custom domains created were redirected to the subdomain (e.g. [askdifferent.com](https://askdifferent.com)). You can find the full explanation for the reversal on the blog:

- [Domain Names: The Wrong Question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/05/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

There are still other sites which use custom domains:

- [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net) because [MathOverflow was an SE 1.0 site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277069/mathoverflow-why-so-different).
- [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com)
- [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com)

Comment: So I guess a better question would be, why does SE not have these other sites (like trilogy) under sub domains too? Why not redirect like the others you mentioned?