# Left Nav, new theming and responsiveness - is this a fait accompli?

Tags: discussion, design, new-nav

The "Left nav, new theming and responsiveness" has [gone live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/286574).

Although the March 12th (2018) post about the [motivations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/286574) for this was well-received at a net +141 votes, the actual [rollout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/286574) wasn't, at a whopping net -198 votes last time I checked.

On English Language & Usage, the [preview](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11693/142322) post garnered +10/-23 votes, compared to +26/-1 for the [existing theme](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/400/142322).

The new theme looks pretty unpopular, so my question is this: is the roll-out a *fait accompli* that the community can only tweak a little here and there, or is it possible for either individual communities or Stack Exchange as a whole to vote to **not** proceed with the planned changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible for either individual communities or Stack Exchange as a whole to vote to not proceed with the planned changes?

No. The new design is a necessary evil; the existing diversification prevented roll-out of new features, such as the site being responsive. With the [reduced amount of development (wo)manpower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303005/295232) Stack Exchange has, this was the only way to go forward. Judging by the score of the [motivations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/295232) post I feel that the community at least *understood* the reasons for this executive decision, but isn't really happy about the outcome. It's almost beginning to look like real-world politics...

My guess (but I'm not a Stack Exchange employee) is that only [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) and [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) will keep the current designs. Area 51 is running on a very old 'version' of Stack Exchange anyway, and MathOverflow has had the right to certain exceptions [from the very beginning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277069/295232); right now, they're still using the ancient "1.0 design".

I guess the only way to prevent the planned changes right now is to arrange a lot of money, buy the Stack Overflow company, hire some more developers and have them try to reintroduce the diversification.

Comment: Good point about cost constraints. Out of curiosity - how much *does* it cost to run Stack Exchange?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Maybe it's mentioned in one of the blogs (though then it's probably outdated); it might be an idea for another question though I'm not sure if it would be welcomed.

Comment: -1 Many of the "improvements" have absolutely no effect whatsoever on site maintainability or responsiveness. For example, the vote buttons and the like are part of the _same exact image resource_ as the banner.