# Put the right column into the new theme's left column

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, new-nav

The [new theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/286574) that's currently moving into beta is intended to be more uniform and 'responsive'. Much of the response so far has been negative, but it seems that it's [here to stay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315122/286574).

Some of the complaints are:

1. the new left column is [rather bare](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1016896_310908);
2. the [font size has shrunk](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11709/142322) to accommodate the sideways growth; and
3. the right column has elements that [many don't use](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11735/142322).

We can resolve all of them if we **migrate all the elements** from the right column into the 'left nav'. Here are the benefits:

- the left nav gets filled with potentially useful elements;
- the questions (Stack Exchange's *raison d’être*) can have a larger font size; and
- those who don't want the extra elements can hide the left nav.

So ... can we please remove the entire right column and move its elements into the left nav?

Comment: I would love some kind of question feed on the left hand side, so much blank space +1

Comment: +1 as well - we can expand the meta posts box (the yellow box on the right hand side)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315122/left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness-is-this-a-fait-accompli

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316019/162102