# Hot network posts not shown in MathOverflow

Tags: bug, hot-questions, mathoverflow

I've been exploring some of the Hot Network Questions and I noticed that it doesn't show on https://mathoverflow.net/

I suspect it's a bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug. [Mathoverflow is a bit different from other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277072/369802). One of the consequenses is that they don't have the hot network questions:

> They prefer not having the hot questions list, and the design is adapted from an older design created while they were still an SE 1.0 site as far as I know.