# Hot Network Questions missing on MathOverflow

Tags: bug, hot-questions, mathoverflow

I was visiting the Hot Network Questions list, and ended up at https://mathoverflow.net/questions

But for that specific site, the Hot Network Questions seem to be missing.

Is this a bug?

Comment: See: [Hot network posts not shown in MathOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341908) and [Mathoverflow - why so different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277069).

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, so it appears this is a dupe. Isn't it a bit unfair though to have mathoverflow advertised in the HNQ, but itself not advertising anybody else? They should probably be excluded from the HNQ until they participate.

Comment: I am not really sure about that - but that would be a topic for separate discussion. (Some MO users actually suggested that they would prefer MO not to be shown in the HNQ. You could find several related discussions on MathOverflow Meta, such as: [Measures to separate math overflow from the rest of the stack exchange network](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1305), [Traffic from the list of hot network questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1388), [Featured MO questions on the hot list: what benefits, if any, do these bring?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1350), etc.)

Comment: hmm to me this looks like a reasonably fair deal. Stack Exchange has got a mature reputable site under their umbrella, to become more attractive for particular audience and in return they gave mathoverflow means to promote network-wide using HNQ

Comment: It looks like it's missing on https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions too

Comment: @user000001 regarding Aviation.SE: not repro'd, unless [it's deliberately hidden](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).