# There are many sites ending in "Overflow". Are these affiliated?

Tags: discussion

Many sites use "Overflow" in their names:

- [arrayoverflow.com](https://arrayoverflow.com/)
- [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/)
- [techoverflow.net](https://techoverflow.net/)

Are any of these Stack Exchange sites? If so, what should a Stack Exchange site have that distinguishes it from other sites?

(I'm not asking for legal advice, just info about if they're affiliated or not.)

Comment: Related: [Mathoverflow - why so different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277069/348196).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog What does that have to do with whether these are Stack Exchange sites or not?

Comment: @Anonymous As the trademark policy linked in the answer to that post says, it's allowed for others to use the name "Overflow" on a site without infringing on Stack Overflow's trademark.

Comment: @Sonic The OP has clarified that they're not asking whether it's allowed or not though. They're asking a) whether or not those sites are part of the network, and b) how can they tell (in the future) if a website belongs to the network or not.

Comment: I should note that I was immediately struck by the strong similarity between the ArrayOverflow logo and the StackOverflow logo. Would it be appropriate for SE legal to look into the ramifications of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)  is part of the Stack Exchange network. It's a little different though because it used to be an independent website before it was added to the network. For more information, see: [Mathoverflow - why so different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277069/mathoverflow-why-so-different).

The other two websites are not part of the network and the fact that their names include "overflow" in itself is not an indication that they are affiliated. You can view the full list of all sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

> what should a Stack Exchange site have that distinguishes it from other sites?

There are several identifying elements. Some of the obvious ones to look for:

- Every Stack Exchange site uses the same style of footer with an [About](https://stackoverflow.com/company) link that directs to an article about the Stack Overflow company:

  [image: MathOverflow footer]
- Every Stack Exchange site (aside from Stack Overflow) has the StackExchange logo in its top bar:

  [image: MathOverflow top bar]

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Agreed, but Area51 is a bit different. It's not a Q&A site. It still, however, has the logo and other identifying elements. Also, it _is_ displayed on the "all sites" page (just below the list of Q&A sites). You might want to check [this relevant answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211253/348196).